# PHP Wrap Last and 2nd To Last Letter in Different Spans

Tags: php, regex

I want to wrap the 2nd to last letter in a span with class "testing2" and the last letter in a span with class "testing". I got how to do the last letter, but what about the 2nd to last letter?

```
echo preg_replace('/(.)$/', '<span class="testing">\1</span>', $title)
```

Comment: Please post at least one example with expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex will find the last 2 letters in a string and capture them separately.

```
.*([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]).*$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/yR1sT8/1

PHP Usage:

```
$string = 'aaffffs3.4.4asdf234f4f3_+!#>,3';
preg_match('/.*([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]).*$/', $string, $letters);
print_r($letters);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => aaffffs3.4.4asdf234f4f3_+!#>,3
    [1] => d
    [2] => f
)
```

...or...

```
$string = 'aaffffs3.4.4asdf234f4f3_+!#>,3';
echo preg_replace('/.*([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]).*$/', '<span class="testing2">$1</span><span class="testing">$2</span>',$string);
```

Output:

```
<span class="testing2">d</span><span class="testing">f</span>
```

If you didn't care about the last `letters` and just wanted any character than this was much easier and just, `(.)(.)$`.

Possible alternative: https://regex101.com/r/yR1sT8/2

**Update:**

To keep the previous values as well we just need to add additional capture groups.

```
$string = 'aaffffs3.4.4asdf234f4f3_+!#>,3';
echo preg_replace('/(.*)([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z])(.*)$/', '$1<span class="testing2">$2</span><span class="testing">$3</span>$4',$string);
```

Output:

```
aaffffs3.4.4as<span class="testing2">d</span><span class="testing">f</span>234f4f3_+!#>,3
```

**Additional:**

The `()` is a capture group. Anything inside those is grouped which can be used in a number of ways. For example say you wanted to evaluate a sentence and you didn't care the word `the` started it, you could do.

```
`(?:The)? wolf was walking down the street`
```

Here `the` is grouped and the `?` makes that whole word optional. The `?:` makes the capturing group not capture so `$1` wouldn't be present here. The `$1`, `$2`, etc. are named on the order they appear in the regex. You can read more about capture groups here, http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html and 
http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html. Depending on the language the reference to the captured value maybe `\1`.

Comment: Thanks Chris. But this is only returning the last 2 letters wrapped in span. I would like to return the entire phrase, along with the last 2 letters with new spans.

Comment: You can just do it for the last option with preg_replace. That is the route I'll go with.

Comment: Perfect - thanks! So each expression wrapped in ( ) is represented in output string by $1, $2, etc. Correct?

Comment: I'll add a write up on capture groups as well.

Comment: Okay, updated with capture group write up and some links on it.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would be an [assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead of just `$`:

```
(?=.$|$)
```

This would lead the `(.)` to match at the end *and* one letter before that.